# Convert a list of variables to a dictionary of varName / varValue pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some variables: `var1=11` `var2=22` `var3=33` etc. EDIT: Sorry, the names are more specific... "spam", "eggs", "jokes" etc. They are not numbered in a series.

The values are stored in a list: `myList = (var1, var2, var3)` Should be `myList = (spam, eggs, jokes)`

How can I convert `myList` to a dictionary of varName:varValue pairs?
i.e. `myDict = {'spam':11, 'eggs':22, 'jokes':33}`

I have a reason for needing to do this. The values of the variables are stored in a list after having formatting done by another function that returns a list of the formatted values. For reasons of readability, I would like to refer to the formatted variables by their original names rather than by myList[0] myList[1] etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values stored in a list don't have names; your list contains `(11, 22, 33)`, and the original variable names are not transfered to the list.

You can provide your own keys instead:

```
my_list = [11, 22, 33]
my_keys = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']

my_dict = dict(zip(my_keys, my_list))
```

`zip()` pairs up the elements of `my_list` and `my_keys`, creating a list of key-value tuples. `dict()` takes that list and produces a dictionary from those.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The names aren't in the list. So,, it makes sense to something like you suggest. :>)

Answer (score 0):

For an undefined number of variables, you can do it as follows:

```
var_names = ['spam','eggs','jokes',...]
myList = (11,22,33,.....)

myDict = {}
for i in range(len(myList)):
    myDict[var_names[i]] = myList[i]
```

Comment: Sorry, I named the variables badly. They have more specific names like "spam", "eggs", "jokes" etc. So adding a series of numbers won't work.

Comment: @flanna, in that case, you need to have a list of variable names like:  `var_names = ['spam', 'eggs', 'jokes', etc...]` I will update my answer now.

Comment: @flanna, sorry for taking so long. I have updated my answer. Works for  different var names.